# Why can't we have some AntiXss Literal html tag

Tags: html, xss, security

Nowadays I am learning about web security, XSS, etc. As XSS basically targets a client-agent (web browser) by injecting some malicious code that is executed by the web browser as it was inserted by an  authenticated user. Now the question is **Why can't we have a tag in html that just shows literals and prevents the execution of anything inside it?**

Something like:

```
<!-- The code below will not be executed and just treated as literal content by a web browser -->

<ltrl>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('You have been xssed');</script>
</ltrl>
```

So if I would have something like this in html then it were shown as

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('You have been xssed');</script>
```

in web browser.

Comment: You just described the `<pre>` tag. Creating a new tag won't stop the user input from including a closing tag of the same name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose the contents of the text supplied by the attacker was:

```
</ltrl>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('You have been xssed');</script>
<ltrl>
```

the total markup would be

```
<ltrl>
</ltrl>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('You have been xssed');</script>
<ltrl>
</ltrl>
```

and your defence has been trivially breached.