# Does it bother anyone else that the code tag doesn't print the containing text as a literal?

Tags: html

It seems like this should be rectified in HTML5 or at least the spec should specify that the `<code>` tag does this.

As of now if you have tags inside the code tag, it considers those DOM elements.

There should be a way to write tags without having to escape them. Am I missing something or is this ridiculous that they haven’t thought of this?

Comment: Are you asking something, or are you just wondering why something isn't what you expect? You should rephrase this to be less of a rant if you don't want it to get closed.

Comment: The `<code>` tag isn't just for HTML/XML code, it's for *all* code types.  If you using XHTML, you may be able to use `<![CDATA[ ]]>`.

Comment: It's a simple question: is this how we expect the <code> tag to function? Am I asking the question because I'm annoyed? Yes. Because this should've been thought of when the <code> tag was introduced in HTML 3. It is ridiculous that html tags cannot be printed literally and have to be escaped. XSS would be less of an issue if they had let string literals be printed as string literals.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: As a point of HTML history, the `<code>` element was in HTML 2.0

Comment: For why this approach is no use against XSS attacks, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692252/why-cant-we-have-some-antixss-literal-html-tag/8692944#8692944

Comment: Can you please [edit] to make this a constructive question rather than a ranty complaint?

Answer (score 4):

This kind of feature was thought of, even before HTML 2.0 was published, the use case being met by the `<xmp>` and `<listing>` elements rather than `<code>`, but by the time HTML 2.0 was finalised, the elements were already deprecated because it causes problems - how do you put `</xmp>` inside your escaped code?

Having said that, `<xmp>` is pretty consistently implemented these days, and came reasonably close to being made valid in HTML5. The quotes below come from HTML5 editor Ian Hickson's comments on [Bug 12235 - Make `<xmp>` conforming](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12235).

> Proposal: allow `<xmp>` as an element with the same semantics as `<pre>`
>   but keeping the special parsing rules in HTML.
>
> Pros: Experienced authors who are writing specs, HTML tutorials,
>   programming language blogs, or other pages containing snippets of code
>   that can be expected to contain `<` and `&` characters get to save the
>   time of escaping their `<`s and `&`s.
>
> Cons: Complicates the language, introduces yet another polyglot
>   difference, may be mistreated as a security feature, a pain to use if
>   you have to later add markup inside the block (e.g. to highlight a
>   section), doesn't support characters outside the character encoding of
>   the page (as it can't get entities).
>
> I agree with Henri that this is a tough call.

--

> Status: Rejected Change
>
> Description: no spec change
>
> Rationale: I'm
>   going to say no on this, mostly driven by the simplicity argument.
>   It's a tough call, though. There's some good arguments on both sides.

Finally, I should note that the behaviour of `<code>` can't change. Doing so now would break many, many web pages.

Comment: (Some dumbasses closed this.) What's wrong with treating this as a security feature? It could prevent XSS attacks that are written to the page.